# Django request XML file

Tags: python, xml, django

Hi I'm trying to send a XML file from one view to another.

First view (In this view I send the XML):

```
def view1(request):
    xml_file = open("/path/to/respuesta_error.xml", "rb").read()
    r = urllib2.Request("http://localhost:8000/ingram/response/", data=xml_file, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml'})
    u = urllib2.urlopen(r)
    response = u.read()
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Second view (In this view I should read the XML):

```
@csrf_exempt
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element
def view2(request):
    xml_file = open("/path/to/respuesta_error.xml", "rb") # <-- How can I read the request XML?
    text = xml_file.read()
    text = strip_ns(text)

    file_new = open("ultima_respuesta.xml", "w")
    file_new.write(texto)
    file_new.close()

    return HttpResponse("test")
```

With that, in view2 I read the file /path/to/respuesta_error.xml, I don't know what I should do to read the XML file sent by POST from view1.

I tried with request and request.body but doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that request.body contains the XML as a string, so the ***view2*** should be like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element
def view2(request):
    text = strip_ns(request.body)

    file_new = open("ultima_respuesta.xml", "w")
    file_new.write(texto)
    file_new.close()

    return HttpResponse("test")
```

Comment: You could also use `request.read()` ? Also since your method is POST you may need to check it as well. By default the view addresses "GET" method AFAIK.

Comment: Okey, thanks I will check if the method is POST. Why is better use request.read()?